# How do I randomly remove a certain fraction of a file’s lines?

Tags: perl, random

I am using a visualizer to view atom probe data.

My output files contain 4 columns. Each line contains x, y, and z coordinates of the atom plus an intensity value that determines which atom it is. Each element in the system has an output file.

I have code that counts the number of lines in each output file and divides that by the total to calculate the composition of the system. For example, if the sum of all the number of lines in each output file is 100 and my iron atom output file contains 85 lines then 85% of the system is made up of iron atoms.

Now, I want to reduce the number of iron atoms so it’s easier to see the other atoms. How can I randomly remove 90% of the lines from the output file? I want to make something like this conditional:

```
if ($atom>80) {      #such as iron being 85
    #randomly remove lines, perhaps with rand()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rand` function produces a real value in the interval [0, 1). If we want a condition that returns true 90% of the time, we can write `rand() < 0.9`. As you only want to keep 10% of iron atoms:

```
my $percentage = shift @ARGV;
while (<>) {
  print unless this_record_is_iron() && rand() < $percentage;
}
```

Then:

```
$ perl reduce_iron.pl 0.9 input-data >reduced-data
```

---

If we want to delete exactly 90%, then I'd read in the whole file, make an array of indices that point to iron records, shuffle the index list, and delete all but the last 10%:

```
use List::Util qw/shuffle/;
my $percentage = shift @ARGV;
my(@lines, @iron_idx);
while (<>) {
  push @lines, $_;
  push @iron_idx, $#lines if this_record_is_iron();
}
@iron_idx = (shuffle @iron_idx)[0 .. @iron_idx * $percentage - 1]; # keep indices to delete
$_ = "" for @lines[@iron_idx];
print @lines;
```

Comment: Is it possible for this to not remove exactly 10% of the lines? For example, if we have 100 lines, could we end up with 89 or 91?

Comment: @Matt My first solution is *random*. On average, we'll delete `$percentage` amount of lines. I added another solution that is more exact; it will delete `floor(ironAtoms · percentage)` records. As this requires us to know the number of iron atoms, we have to read in the whole file, which is inefficient for large data sets.

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this into my code. The problem is that I open an output file, write in the 4 columns of data and close it for several ions (i.e., if there are several Fe atoms with different charges, they all have their own file). Then I use cat to combine all ions of the same element. Now, if the new element file makes up a large enough portion of the system (e.g., 80%), I want to randomly remove 90% of that file.

Comment: @IzaakWilliamson I don't have your code, so I can't know how this could be integrated. I just provided two ways to delete 90% (`rand` or `shuffle`). It seems like you should count the total number of atoms in the system and the number of iron atoms. If the ratio crosses some threshold, you can then delete an appropriate percentage of iron atoms. This doesn't seem difficult, even though my code isn't copy&paste-ready.

Answer (score 0):

A thinning implementation that uses [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw/ SEEK_SET /;

die "Usage: $0 fraction file\n" .
    "  where 1 <= fraction <= 99\n"
  unless @ARGV == 2;

my($fraction,$path) = @ARGV;
die "$0: invalid fraction: $fraction"
  unless $fraction =~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $fraction >= 1 && $fraction <= 99;

open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";
my $lines;
++$lines while defined($_ = <$fh>);

# modified Algorithm R from Knuth's TAoCP Volume 2, pg. 144
my $rsize = my $samples = int (($lines / 100) * $fraction);
my @delete = (1 .. $samples);
foreach my $t ($samples+1 .. $lines) {
  my $m = int(rand $t) + 1;
  $delete[$m] = ++$rsize if $m <= $samples;
}

seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET or die "$0: seek: $!";
my %delete = map +($_ => 1), @delete;
$. = 1;
while (<$fh>) {
  print unless delete $delete{$.};
}
```